# Singular Covariance and NA's for z value using Random Projection in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm getting NA's for my z value in the following code. I get that it's due to singular covariance. I've run a similar test on the iris dataset, and I don't get the same error. Am I doing something wrong or is it the nature of the data?

Code in R:

```
install.packages('mclust')
library('mclust')

mydata <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE);

est <- meVVV(mydata[,-12], unmap(mydata[,12]))

randProj(mydata[,-12], seeds=200, parameters = variance, z = est$z, truth = iris[,5],
         what = "errors", identify = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

Thanks,

dgene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this

```
table(mydata[, 12]) 
# 3   4   5   6   7   8 
# 10  53 681 638 199  18
```

this means that you are using `10` observations in one cluster, while you have `11` features (variables) in you model, thus the warning message an `NA` values.

If you want to specify the model `VVV` then use this code :

```
 fm <- Mclust(mydata[, -12],  modelNames="VVV")
```